How does the differential of the homogenization depend on the original function?
Let $f:S^{n-1}_r\to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function. Here $r$ denotes the radius of the sphere. Consider the positively homogeneous function
$$
f_r(x) = \lVert x\rVert \,f\!\left(\frac{rx}{\lVert x\rVert}\right) 
$$
Let's denote by $\widehat{x} = \dfrac{x}{\lVert x\rVert}$. I found that
$$
df_r(x) = \widehat{x} \, f(r\widehat{x}) 
+ df(r\widehat{x}) 
$$
To do this I computed the differential directly:
$$
\begin{aligned} 
\partial_if_r(x) &= \frac{x_i}{\lVert x\rVert} f(r\widehat{x}) 
+ \lVert x\rVert \, df(r\widehat{x}) \cdot 
r\left(\frac{e_i}{\Vert x\Vert} - \frac{x_i}{\lVert x\rVert^3}x\right) \\ 
&= \frac{x_i}{\lVert x\rVert} f(r\widehat{x}) 
+ \partial_i f(r\widehat{x}) 
- \frac{x_i}{\lVert x\rVert} \, 
df(r\widehat{x})\cdot \widehat{x}
\end{aligned} 
$$
The last term should be zero, because $f$ can be thought of as a homogeneous function of degree $0$, and then using the Euler's differential equation. Then the complete differential is
$$
df_r(x) = \widehat{x} \, f(r\widehat{x}) + df(r\widehat{x}).
$$
I don't show how I got the expression for $\partial_i f_r$ because that's just a tedious computation using product rule. I have two questions:

Is the answer correct? Did I get the derivative in the correct form? It makes sense when $f$ is just a constant function, then $f_r = c\lVert x\rVert$. In that case, the derivative matches.
Is there a nice way to prove this? Maybe a more slick proof which doesn't involve just computing every differential by hand. This is the one I care about most, assuming I got the derivative right.


Your equation for the complete differential doesn't quite make sense. I recommend steering clear of partial derivatives entirely.
I find it easier to think in (generalized) polar coordinates. Write $x=ty$ with $t>0$ and $y\in S^{n-1}_r$. Then $f_r(x)=f_r(ty)=rtf(y)$. Then the radial derivative is given by
$$\frac \partial{\partial t} f_r(ty) = rf(y),$$
and the derivative in the direction of a vector $v$ tangent to the sphere passing through $x=ty$ is given by
$$df_r(x)(v) = rt\, df(y)(v/t).$$
The best way to see this is to compute the directional derivative in direction $v$ by the definition: If $\gamma(s)$ is a curve in the sphere of radius $rt$ with $\gamma(0)=x$ and $\gamma'(0)=v$, then
$$df_r(x)(v) = (f_r\circ\gamma)'(0) = rt\frac d{ds}\Big|_{s=0} f(\gamma(s)/t) = rt\, df(y)(v/t) = \|x\| df(y)(rv/\|x\|).$$

This is truly a very slick answer, thank you for the insight. Correct me if I'm wrong but I think the mistake in my answer is that $df(r\widehat{x})$ is a functional on the tangent space of the sphere, whereas $df_r$ should be a functional on the tangent space of the Euclidean space. But from what you have written is it possible to extract a formula for $df_r(x)(v)$ in terms of some vector $v$? I ask it because I was expecting the radial component to be something like $ryf(y)$ but you have gotten only $rf(y)$. I don't understand where I am going wrong.

The function $f_r$ is still scalar-valued, so I don't know what you mean by expecting the radial component to be a vector. You can certainly write my answer explicitly as a dot product with $v$ (scaled by $1/t$). The point is that $f$ is a function only on the sphere, and so you can input into its derivative only tangent vectors to that sphere.

I was trying to compare it with the other answer, which makes more sense to me and if I understand it correctly, intuitively it feels like the radial part corresponds to the $\hat{x}f(r\hat{x})$ but I don't understand how to see it. Also, in the second half, if $v$ is orthogonal to $y$(i.e. tangent to the sphere) how do I see the scaling $v/t$? I understand the $v\cdot \hat{x}=0$ so that term doesn't appear there. But comparing to the other ans I don't understand how to see it. I do agree with your computation, and with that logic we do get $v/t$, but I want to understand it differently.

The vector $x$ has magnitude $rt$. When you project it to the sphere of radius $r$, you apply the dilatation $\phi(u)=u/t$, which, being linear, induces the same map from the tangent space of the sohere of radius $rt$ to that of the sphere of radius $r$.

I'm partial to using the direction derivative for something like this.
We want to calculate
\begin{align*}
v\cdot\nabla f_r(x) &= D_vf_r(x)\\
 &= \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}f_r(x+tv)\\
&= \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}|x+tv|f\left(\frac{r(x+tv)}{|x+tv|}\right).
\end{align*}
To compute this, observe that
\begin{align*}
\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}|x+tv| &= \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}((x+tv)\cdot(x+tv))^{1/2}\\
&= v\cdot\hat{x}\\
\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\frac{x+tv}{|x+tv|} &= \frac{v}{|x|}-\frac{(v\cdot x)x}{|x|^3}\\
&= \frac{v-(v\cdot\hat{x})\hat{x}}{|x|},
\end{align*}
where
$$ \hat{x} = \frac{x}{|x|}. $$
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
D_vf_r(x) &= (v\cdot\hat{x})f(r\hat{x})+ r(v-(v\cdot\hat{x})\hat{x})\cdot\nabla f(rx)\\
&= v\cdot(\hat{x}f(r\hat{x})+r(\nabla f(r\hat{x}) - (\hat{x}\cdot\nabla f(r\hat{x}))\hat{x})\\
\end{align*}
It follows that
\begin{align*}
\nabla f_r(x) &= r(\nabla f(r\hat{x}) - (\hat{x}\cdot\nabla f(r\hat{x}))\hat{x}) + \hat{x}f(r\hat{x}),
\end{align*}

Just to clarify, in the second line where you compute $D_vf_r(x)$, the second term should be $r(\nabla f(r\hat{x})-(\hat{x}\cdot \nabla f(r\hat{x})) \hat{x})$? I think when you compute $D_v$ it doesn't match this expression, but it does seem to match your final answer. Do you agree with my understanding or am I getting something wrong?

Yes, thanks for pointing out the error.
